# override existing service.xml in liferay

Tags: liferay

I need to add a column to the existing table in liferay.
I think overriding `service.xml` is the way to add a column to the existing table.The required `service.xml` is present in `portal-impl\src\com\liferay\portal`. 
Now I want to know where to override this file (I am using tomcat and `postgreSQL`).

Answer (score 5):

It's best practice to not do this to Liferay's tables - imagine what would happen if the next version of Liferay adds the same column, but with different semantics.

Further, it's discouraged to change the sourcecode directly - rather use plugins like hooks (or, possible but not recommended unless absolutely necessary, ext). Note that servicebuilder changes are deprecated in ext and will not be supported in future, so you're stuck with hooks which can not add directly to Liferay's tables.

The recommended way to implement additional fields is to either use custom fields (API-name `Expando*`) or create new entities with new services (from hooks or portlets) and link these with foreign keys to the Liferay entities.

I know, this does not answer your question of how to do this, but it gives the alternative of how you should think to solve the underlying problem that you don't mention.

Comment: +1 for "It's best practice to not do this to Liferay's tables - imagine what would happen if the next version of Liferay adds the same column, but with different semantics."